# Why am I getting a "503 server has been shutdown" from an Azure App service during a slot swap?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to debug an issue where I'm getting intermittent failures/downtime on an app service slot swap for a test service I've built.  I have two slots in the test app: prod and staging.  I deployed to staging, tested, and then initiated a swap to prod.  In order to trace, I had the API in both instances return a unique value on its health check endpoint, and then proceeded to call the health check constantly during the swap operation.  What I found was kind of interesting:

1. Requests started out going to prod (as expected)
2. I'd get a 2-10 failures (503 server has been shut down)
3. I'd get at least one success response from the prod slot (note, I'm using Postman to hit the API here, so there might be parallel requests going on that mean this is just a delayed response getting in after the failures)
4. I'd start getting responses from the dev slot (swap is complete)

From [this docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal#what-happens-during-a-swap), the implication is that the staging slot is restarted, and then the DNS is flipped to prod.  I did try setting both WEBSITE_WARMUP_PATH and WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_PATH on both slots to make sure that a-the configs were the same, and b-that the staging slot was warm (returning a valid health check) before the swap happened.  Even with these settings though, I would get at least one or two 503s in the process of the swap, which seems like it shouldn't happen.  Is something happening to restart the prod slot before the staging slot is completely swapped in, or is this a case of DNS just not updating quickly enough?  Is there a way to make this a truly zero-downtime swap, like perhaps delaying restarting the prod instances post-swap?

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as off topic, but I managed to find an answer.  It turns out that setting WEBSITE_ADD_SITENAME_BINDINGS_IN_APPHOST_CONFIG=1 in both slots worked (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal#troubleshoot-swaps).  Once that was in place, zero 503s on swap.